# Redirect a folder containing images to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have two folder in my local server `MyApp` & `Images` and respetively there url server are `http://localhost/myapp/` && `http://localhost/images/`. What I'm trying to do here (If possible) is to be able to show images from the folder `Images` in `http://localhost/myapp/`, for example there are multiple subdirectories in `Images` like `Nature\nature.jpg`, if I type: `http://localhost/images/Nature/nature.jpg` the images shows great,when I type `http://localhost/myapp/Nature/nature.jpg` it show's `object not found` which is pretty normal since I didn't configure my .htaccess in `MyApp` folder. And now that I did it still don't work.
Here's what I've tried already and didn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule http://localhost/images/(.*)$ http://localhost/myapp/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any help please, I've bustin' my head all today and haven't found a solution yet . Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule in `/MyApp/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|ico|png))$ /images/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```